# Eclipse crashes hard trying to find symbols

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

I'm using version 23.0.0.1245622 on linux Mint 17.
Whenever I make the mistake of pausing having typed a period after a symbol, it tries to find all valid completions, then crashes hard - by which I mean it silently disappears without even saving anything.
I've got an error log; but it's 1334 lines, so probably not worth posting all of it.
It starts with this:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xa680f86d, pid=12888, tid=3075888896
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_91-b02) (build 1.7.0_91-b02)
# Java VM: OpenJDK Client VM (24.91-b01 mixed mode, sharing linux-x86 )
# Derivative: IcedTea 2.6.3
# Distribution: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, package 7u91-2.6.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsoup-2.4.so.1+0x5486d]  soup_session_feature_detach+0x1d
#
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

If no-one has any ideas, can anyone tell me how to stop the IDE from performing those automatic symbol look-ups?  It'll be a pain programming without them; but better than crashing every two minutes.

Comment: Report it at http://bugs.java.com/

Comment: I don't know that it's really a java problem; and the eclipse bug reporting system required me to jump through hoops.  None of which will help me actually solve the problem.